# CODE Change the text of a cell based on the value of three other cells

Tags: vba, excel

Everyone.

I am currently using the below code to change the text of cells based on what text is in other cells. What I would also like to do, is on some cells change the text based on the Number/Date in those cells.

Example: if J2, K2 and L2 are either a date or a number, enter "N" into cell N2. Any ideas which function would work for this?

Code currently using to change text based on text:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Row > 1 Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Select Case Target.Column
            Case Columns("G:G").Column
                If UCase(Target.Text) = "Y" Then
                    Target = UCase(Target.Text)
                    Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = "N"
                    Range("M" & Target.Row).Value = "N"
                End If
            Case Columns("F:F").Column
                If UCase(Target.Text) = "CAR" Or UCase(Target.Text) = "BIKE" Then
                    Target = UCase(Target.Text)
                        Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = "N"
                            ElseIf UCase(Target.Text) = "N" Then
                                Target = UCase(Target.Text)
                                    Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = "Y"
                                    Range("G" & Target.Row).Value = "N"
                                    Range("H" & Target.Row).Value = ""
                End If
            Case Columns("F:F").Column
                If UCase(Target.Text) = "N" Then
                    Target = UCase(Target.Text)
                        Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = "Y"
                End If
            Case Columns("G:G").Column
                If UCase(Target.Text) = "Y" Then
                    Target = UCase(Target.Text)
                        Range("I" & Target.Row).Value = "N"
                End If
        End Select
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Why do you need VBA? This can be done by formula I think. Just curious.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom function to do this, call it like:

```
MsgBox(IsNumberOrDate(Range("J2:L2")))
```

Or for non-contiguous cells:

```
MsgBox(IsNumberOrdate(Range("J2", "F2")))
```

Here is how you can do that.  Create a function that returns a boolean value. Send the array of values to the function, which will then iterate the item values in the array, testing whether each is *either* numeric or date (that might actually be redundant unless your dates are string), if any of the items is *neither*, then the function returns `False`. If *all* items are either date/numeric, then the function returns `True`.  You may need to modify it slightly depending on what you want to do with empty cells (these would evaluate as *numeric*), ordinarily.

```
Function IsNumberOrDate(values As Variant) As Boolean
Dim ret As Boolean
Dim v As Variant
For Each v In values
    If IsNumeric(v) Or IsDate(v) Then
        ret = True
    Else
        ret = False
        Exit For
    End If
Next

IsNumberOrDate = ret

End Function
```

So in your case, you can do like:

```
If IsNumberOrDate(Range("J2:L2")) Then
     'do something if all items ARE number or date
     MsgBox "All values are numeric/date", vbOkOnly
Else
     'do something else if they are not
     MsgBox "NOT all values are numeric/date", vbCritical
End If
```